# Get result by Multiple Parameter

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
Table1  --------------------------Table2
ID Name                      Table1_id        Name     
1  Data One                    1             a 
2  Data Two                    1             b 
3  Data Three                  1             c
                               2             a
                               2             c 
                               3             a
                               3             b
                               3             c
```

I will send as parameter values `a` and `b`. I need to get result `Data one` and `Data three`

Look carefully in `table2` as `id` `2` doesn't have `a` and `b`.  `a` and `b` only have `id` `1` and `2`.

I need this result as distinct.

Comment: Paramilitary? Do we mean parameter?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could you show the result you need?

Comment: Extremely sorry for my spelling  mistake , yes i got my  answer  here is query                            SELECT a.id, a.name_eng,a.name_bn,a.image FROM bus a WHERE a.id IN ( SELECT b.bus_id FROM destinations b WHERE b.name in ('destination_c','destination_d') GROUP BY b.bus_id HAVING count(DISTINCT b.name) = 2 )

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to solve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM table2
    WHERE name in ('a','b')
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING count(DISTINCT name) = 2
)
```

That subquery will return only `id` where there are records with both `a` and `b` for a `name`.

Comment: shouldn't that be ">=2" ?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I changed it to `Count(Distinct name)` so that it's unnecessary and also accounts for issues where two records in `table2` contain `name='a'` which would cause some issues...

Comment: there is a join in table2.table1_id=table1.id

Comment: You can absolutely do the join and use the same type of logic to dedup after that join. Depending on your result set that is returned in that subquery, a join may be quicker. Here, though, I am isolating the logic used to perform this check in the subquery to lessen the confusion about it was solved. This is the type of question that has a few ways to solve it too, so you may find one way quicker than others or easier to understand than others.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   t1.Name
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2v1 ON t2v1.Table1_id=t1.id
   AND t2v1.name='a'
INNER JOIN Table2 t2v2 ON t2v2.Table1_id=t1.id
   AND t2v1.name='b'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `exists`:

```
selet t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.table1_id = t1.id and t2.name = 'a') and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.table1_id = t1.id and t2.name = 'b');
```

I'm a big fan of using `group by` and `having` when only one table is involved.  In a situation like this, `exists` is usually better.  In particular, it can take advantage of an index on `table(table1_id, name)`, so it should be quite fast.

The version with `join`s and `select distinct` is likely to have performance issues.